# How do I change where imported objects appear in the world?

Tags: import, world, origin

All objects I import go the center of the grid. Is there anyway to change this.

Comment: all you gotta do is simply remove the location keyframes from the imported objects.

Comment: when you find the above doesn't work for your animated FBX, just use Delta Transform to move stuff around away from the world origin... thank goodness for Delta Transform

Answer (score 0):

Objects appear in the center of the world because that is where the 3D cursor is set by default.

All objects have what is called an origin (a pivot point or a "center", usually represented by an orange dot) The origin of the the created object is then placed where the 3D cursor is on the scene.

[image]

But you can move the 3D cursor wherever you want the new objects to appear. Note that the origin of the new object will be at the 3D cursor's position.

[image]

To have your objects appear in a different place, just move the 3D cursor.

[image]

Comment: Note that you can also use Shift + Right click to move the cursor in a much simpler (although less precise) way than shown in the last demonstration.

Comment: Use shift-C to move the 3D cursor back to the center if you have moved it.

Comment: Somehow that doesn't always work. I have my cursor set at desired location. Then I import a few fbx files, and all the items still get created at 0 world location and not at the cursor.

Comment: the question asked about IMPORTED objects, not new added meshes. If i import an object it doesn't position to the 3D cursor. It goes to the center of the world origin.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason blender positions all imported objects at the center of the *World Origin* no matter where your 3D cursor is positioned. But you can move the object to the 3D cursor after it has been imported by making sure it is selected and pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and then pick *Selection to Cursor*. The object will then move to the 3D cursor.

[image]